# Can I use prop.table(table(data$variable)) to get percentages in R?

Tags: r, percentage

I read somewhere that I could use prop.table(table()) in R in order to get a table of proportions. However, the results I get for this vary somewhat from my manual calculations (i.e., looking at table() and then dividing by NROW().) I'm sure it's possible that I committed manual errors in my calculations, but I wanted to make sure there wasn't something logically wrong with using prop.table(table()).

I'm working with gender disaggregated survey data that I've split into two separate datasets for each gender (i.e., women <- data[data$gender == 1]. I'm trying to identify gender disparities, so I want to see the percentage breakdown of responses and compare them.

```
scoreWomen <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e')
scoreMen <- c('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'e')
prop.table(table(scoreWomen))

#a          b          c          d          e 
#0.23076923 0.07692308 0.15384615 0.38461538 0.15384615 

table(scoreWomen)
#a b c d e 
#3 1 2 5 2 
NROW(scoreWomen)
#13
```

In small scale tests, like the code above, the results are the same for manual calculation vs prop.table(table()). HOWEVER, when I use them with my actual data, they're pretty different and vary by several percent. Why would that be? Is there something about prop.table(), or alternatively about NROW(), that I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Do you have `NA` elements in your dataset.  In that case, table might drop it or else you have specify `useNA = 'always'`

Answer (score 0):

There is a chance for difference of values if there are `NA` elements in the dataset

```
scoreWomen <- c(scoreWomen, NA)
prop.table(table(scoreWomen))
#scoreWomen
#         a          b          c          d          e 
#0.23076923 0.07692308 0.15384615 0.38461538 0.15384615 

table(scoreWomen)/NROW(scoreWomen)
#scoreWomen
#         a          b          c          d          e 
#0.21428571 0.07142857 0.14285714 0.35714286 0.14285714
```

---

But, it can be prevented by specifying `useNA = 'always'` in `table`

```
prop.table(table(scoreWomen, useNA = 'always'))
#scoreWomen
#        a          b          c          d          e       <NA> 
#0.21428571 0.07142857 0.14285714 0.35714286 0.14285714 0.07142857
```

Now, it is matching with the calculated value with `NROW` and later remove the `<NA>` element from the table output

So, it all depends on whether the calculation needs to be carried out by removing the `NA` elements or not.  The `NROW` doesn't differentiate the occurence of `NA`